# FLWOR XQuery to return only unique words combinition, and the number of times the combinition occured, sorted in descending order of frequency

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery, flwor

I am making a file containing a XQuery FLWOR expression which returns all the occurrences of the word 'we' in the collection of files, together with the word which comes next in the sentence in each case. I want to use 'distinct-value()' to eliminate the duplicate combinition of words. I also want to count the number of times this combination of words occurred, sorted in descending order of frequency.

This is the XML File I am working on

```
<u who="PS6H7">
<s n="3">
    <w c5="AV0" hw="well" pos="ADV">Well</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="AJ0" hw="good" pos="ADJ">good </w>
    <w c5="NN1" hw="afternoon" pos="SUBST">afternoon</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="PNI" hw="everybody" pos="PRON">everybody</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="i" pos="PRON">I </w>
    <w c5="VVB" hw="think" pos="VERB">think </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we</w>
    <w c5="VHD" hw="have" pos="VERB">'d </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="well" pos="ADV">better </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="get" pos="VERB">get </w>
    <w c5="VVN" hw="start" pos="VERB">started</w>
    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
</s>

<s n="4">
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">We </w>
    <w c5="VVD" hw="look" pos="VERB">looked </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="so" pos="ADV">so </w>
    <w c5="AJ0" hw="thin" pos="ADJ">thin </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="on" pos="PREP">on </w>
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
    <w c5="NN1" hw="ground" pos="SUBST">ground</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="i" pos="PRON">I </w>
    <w c5="VVD" hw="think" pos="VERB">thought </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we</w>
    <w c5="VM0" hw="would" pos="VERB">'d </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="sit" pos="VERB">sit </w>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="wait" pos="VERB">wait </w>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="see" pos="VERB">see </w>
    <w c5="CJS" hw="if" pos="CONJ">if </w>
    <w c5="PNI" hw="everyone" pos="PRON">everyone</w>
    <w c5="VBZ" hw="be" pos="VERB">'s </w>
    <w c5="VVG-AJ0" hw="come" pos="VERB">coming</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="but" pos="CONJ">but </w>
    <w c5="UNC" hw="erm" pos="UNC">erm </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we</w>
    <w c5="VM0" hw="will" pos="VERB">'ll </w>
    <w c5="VHI" hw="have" pos="VERB">have </w>
    <w c5="TO0" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="get" pos="VERB">get </w>
    <w c5="VVN" hw="start" pos="VERB">started </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="anyway" pos="ADV">anyway</w>
    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
</s>

<s n="5">
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">We</w>
    <w c5="VM0" hw="will" pos="VERB">'ll </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="welcome" pos="VERB">welcome</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we </w>
    <w c5="VHB" hw="have" pos="VERB">have </w>
    <w c5="CRD" hw="two" pos="ADJ">two </w>
    <w c5="NN2" hw="speaker" pos="SUBST">speakers</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="mr" pos="SUBST">Mr </w>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="bob" pos="SUBST">Bob </w>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="plumtree" pos="SUBST">Plumtree</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="ms" pos="SUBST">Ms </w>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="erica" pos="SUBST">Erica </w>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="ison" pos="SUBST">Ison</w>
    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
</s>

<s n="6">
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">We </w>
    <w c5="VVD" hw="ask" pos="VERB">asked </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="they" pos="PRON">them </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
    <w c5="NN1" hw="meeting" pos="SUBST">meeting </w>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we </w>
    <w c5="VVB" hw="look" pos="VERB">look </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="forward" pos="ADV">forward </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
    <w c5="VVG-NN1" hw="listen" pos="VERB">listening </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="you" pos="PRON">you </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="later" pos="ADV">later </w>
    <w c5="AVP" hw="on" pos="ADV">on </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="in" pos="PREP">in </w>
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
    <w c5="NN1" hw="agenda" pos="SUBST">agenda</w>
    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
</s>

<s n="7">
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">The </w>
    <w c5="NN2" hw="minute" pos="SUBST">minutes </w>
    <w c5="PRF" hw="of" pos="PREP">of </w>
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
    <w c5="NN1" hw="meeting" pos="SUBST">meeting </w>
    <w c5="VVD-VVN" hw="hold" pos="VERB">held </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="in" pos="PREP">in </w>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="january" pos="SUBST">January</w>
    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
</s>

<s n="8">
    <w c5="DT0" hw="any" pos="ADJ">Any </w>
    <w c5="NN2" hw="correction" pos="SUBST">corrections </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
    <w c5="NN2" hw="minute" pos="SUBST">minutes </w>
    <w c5="ORD" hw="first" pos="ADJ">first</w>
    <c c5="PUN">?</c>
</s>

</u>
```

This is my FLWOR XQuery file. It returns all the occurrences of the word 'we' in the collection of files, together with the word which comes next in the sentence in each case. but it contain many duplicate combinition of words. The distinct-values() is not working properly. Also the count function return 1 in every row.

In result, I want to an HTML table to show the word 'we' in 1st column, the word that occurs after 'we' in 2nd column and the frequency or number of times the combinition occurred in 3rd column

```
<html>
<body>
<table border='1'>
<tr><td>Target</td><td>Successor</td><td>Frequency</td></tr>

{
for $x in doc("KS0.xml")//u//s//w
where lower-case(normalize-space($x))="we"
return <tr>
           <td>{data($x)}</td>
           <td>{data(distinct-values($x/following-sibling::w[1]))}</td>
           <td>{count(distinct-values(data($x/following-sibling::w[1])))}</td>
       </tr>
}

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain which result you want for the sample you have posted?

Comment: In result, I want to an HTML table to show the word 'we' in 1st column, the word that occurs after 'we' in 2nd column and the frequency or number of times the combinition occurred in 3rd column.

Comment: Which version of XQuery do you use?

Comment: I am using XQuery version 1.0

Comment: It would help, if you explicitely specify the wanted output html and show the current output html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping in XQuery 1.0 is a bit complicated and I am not sure I have understood which result you want but here is a suggestion:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border='1'>
<tr><td>Target</td><td>Successor</td><td>Frequency</td></tr>

{
let $s := "we"
let $x := doc("KS0.xml")//u//s//w[lower-case(normalize-space()) = $s]
for $w in distinct-values($x/following-sibling::w[1])
let $g := $x/following-sibling::w[1][. = $w]
order by count($g) descending
return <tr>
           <td>{$s}</td>
           <td>{$w}</td>
           <td>{count($g)}</td>
       </tr>
}

</table>
</body>
</html>
```